# How can I use an npm package that just wraps my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, commonjs

We currently have an npm package for clients to use on their ES6-based projects like React. This main index file of this package has the following shape:

```
export function ourFunction() {

}
```

And clients import this function in the following way:

`import { ourFunction } from "our-package";`

We'd like to instead host our code on a dedicated endpoint and have the npm package act simply as a wrapper to grab that code. What we are most confused about is how we can still keep the import line above the same, so that there is no observable difference to clients using the package.

Comment: That is not how npm and packages are supposed to work.....

Comment: We were confused because https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js does this. We were having trouble understanding how they actually import the code.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly:

if the code will be on a dedicated endpoint, users will need to download it(unlike to npm package, which they previously install).
To achieve this, make your function async and download the code inside function:

```
export async function ourFunction() {
  fetch(path/to/our/code)
   .then(code => ...)
   .catch(err => ...)
```

And user can use next way:

```
import { ourFunction } from "our-package";
ourFunction().then(data => ...)
```

Similar example from Stripe

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
const stripe = await loadStripe('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx');
```